Confused on gas estimation error on my addliq() function
In this code I am creating a liqudity pool, initializing it, and then attempting to provide liqidity. Whenever I call the addliq() I get a gas estimation error for some reason and I have no idea why. I have triple checked all the addresses and I have tried adjust parameters but nothing seems to work.
Code to set and initialize liquidty:
(My erc20 test token was initialized with the ether key word so it is 18 decimals aswell.)
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.25;

// Using npm package imports for a Hardhat or Truffle project
import "@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV3Factory.sol";
import "@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV3Pool.sol";

contract createLpPool
{

    IUniswapV3Factory public immutable factory;
    address public immutable factoryAddress=0x0227628f3F023bb0B980b67D528571c95c6DaC1c;

    address public immutable WETH=0xfFf9976782d46CC05630D1f6eBAb18b2324d6B14;
    address public immutable TEST=insertExampleTestAddressHere;


    uint24 public immutable fee=10000;

    uint256 public immutable amtY=0.15 ether;
    uint256 public immutable amtX=1_000_000 ether;

  
    int24 public  tickSpacing;
    int24 public lowerTick;
    int24 public upperTick;
  

    IUniswapV3Pool public pool;

    event lowerTickEvent(int24 lowerTick);
    event upperTickEvent(int24 upperTick);

    
    
    constructor()
    {
        factory=IUniswapV3Factory(factoryAddress);
    }


    function sqrt(uint256 n) internal pure returns (uint256)
    {

        if (n>0)
        {
            uint256 z=(n+1)/2;
            uint256 y=n;
            while (z<y)
            {
                y=z;
                z=(n/z+z)/2;
                
            }
            return y;
        
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;

        }

    }
[10:29 PM]
 function calcSqrtX96(uint amtx,uint amty) internal pure returns (uint160)
    {
       uint256 ratio=amtx*1 ether/amty;
       uint256 sqrtRatio=sqrt(ratio);
       return uint160(sqrtRatio<<96);
    }

    function makePoolAndInitialize() external
    {
        
       pool=IUniswapV3Pool(factory.createPool(WETH,TEST,fee));
       uint160 sqrtPriceX96=calcSqrtX96(amtX, amtY);
       pool.initialize(sqrtPriceX96);



       tickSpacing = pool.tickSpacing();
       (, int24 curTick, , , , , ) = pool.slot0();
        curTick = curTick - (curTick % tickSpacing);
        lowerTick = curTick - (tickSpacing * 2);
        upperTick = curTick + (tickSpacing * 2);
        require(curTick % tickSpacing == 0, 'tick error');

         emit lowerTickEvent(lowerTick);
         emit upperTickEvent(upperTick);
        
       

    }
}

And then here is the code to call the mint function this is the Addliq() where I get the gas estimation error. (Context: I manually sent testtoken and weth to this contract so it has the proper balance)
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.8.25;




import "@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/interfaces/INonfungiblePositionManager.sol";
import "@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/libraries/TransferHelper.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";





contract addLiq
{

    address public immutable weth=0xfFf9976782d46CC05630D1f6eBAb18b2324d6B14;
    address public immutable test=insertTestAddressHere;

    INonfungiblePositionManager public immutable managerAddress;
    address public managerAddy=0x1238536071E1c677A632429e3655c799b22cDA52;

    IERC20 public  WETH;
    IERC20 public  TEST;

    

    uint24 public immutable Fee=10000;


    uint256 public immutable amount0Desired=0.15 ether;
    uint256 public immutable amount1Desired=1_000_000 ether;
    int24 public immutable lowerTick= 571200;
    int24 public  immutable upperTick=572000;
   

   
    event LiquidityAdded(uint256 tokenId, uint256 amount0, uint256 amount1);
    event ErrorHandling(string message);

    constructor()
    {
        WETH=IERC20(weth);
        TEST=IERC20(test);
        managerAddress=INonfungiblePositionManager(managerAddy);
        
    }
[10:34 PM]
    function approve() external 
    {
        //MANUALLY SENT THE AMOUNT OF ETH AND AMOUNT OF TEST TO THIS CONTRACT FROM MY WALLET SO DONT NEED TRANSFER METHOD
    

        // Now approve Uniswap manager to use these tokens
        WETH.approve(address(managerAddress), amount0Desired);
        TEST.approve(address(managerAddress), amount1Desired);

    }


     function addliq()external
     {   // Ensure this contract already has the necessary approvals to Uniswap manager
        INonfungiblePositionManager.MintParams memory params =
        INonfungiblePositionManager.MintParams
        ({
            token0: weth,
            token1: test,
            fee: 10000,
            tickLower: lowerTick,
            tickUpper: upperTick,
            amount0Desired: amount0Desired,
            amount1Desired: amount1Desired,
            amount0Min: 0,
            amount1Min: 0,
            recipient: address(this),
            deadline: block.timestamp + 15 minutes
        });

        
        managerAddress.mint(params);



    }
    
}

Tried changing some of the parameters and double checked all the addresses.

This person @shinado seems to have figured out how to do it in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77234046/uniswapv3-mint-new-position-returned-unexpected-value
I tried using the code here but still no luck might help you guys if you check this as well.
